# malloc does not work as I expected

Tags: c++, malloc

So, I never learnt C++ pointers at University so now im doing it on my own as a hobby. My idea as a learning exercise was to start writing a random number ( 666 ) to a series of memory locations. The thing is some stuff is confusing me ( I started two days ago ). For instance :

1. Why do I use malloc() if I dont know how much memory Ill need until runtime?
2. Why malloc() accepted the value of "1" but then I keep writing until 100 thousands addresses with no problem?
3. Why on the output there is a bunch addresses which have not been "written"?

I know these are all probably dumb newbie question but please bear with me on this one. I'm doing my best effort to learn this on my own.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int limit =0;

    int* x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);

    *x = 10;

    cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Incrementing memory address : " << endl;




    for(int j=0 ; j < 999 ; j++) {
        limit++;
        *x=666;
        x++;
    }
    x-= limit;  
    for(int j=0 ; j < ( limit ) ; j++) {
        cout << x << " " << *x << endl; 
        x++;
    }
    x-= limit;
    free(x);

}
```

#### Output

```
----------------------------------------------------
Incrementing memory address : 
0x55e11d8cae70 666
0x55e11d8cae74 666
0x55e11d8cae78 666
0x55e11d8cae7c 666
0x55e11d8cae80 666
0x55e11d8cae84 666
0x55e11d8cae88 666
0x55e11d8cae8c 666
0x55e11d8cae90 892696624
0x55e11d8cae94 1680945509
0x55e11d8cae98 1700881208
0x55e11d8cae9c 824206137
0x55e11d8caea0 808596530
0x55e11d8caea4 808662326
0x55e11d8caea8 2570
0x55e11d8caeac 666
0x55e11d8caeb0 666
0x55e11d8caeb4 666
0x55e11d8caeb8 666
0x55e11d8caebc 666
0x55e11d8caec0 666
0x55e11d8caec4 666
```

Thanks in advance!

Note - I know the code is not doing anything useful, I'm just playing with C++.

Comment: "*So, I never learnt C++ pointers at University*" - good. Don't learn `malloc` unless you plan to program in `C`. If you are sticking with `C++`, learn `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @Fureeish I dont plan to code in C, nor I develop on it ( actually I work with Angular/html ). This is just a learning exercise and I am not interested on the futility of such.

Comment: You never cast the return of malloc in c.

Comment: Are you aware that you created memory to hold a single `int` but actually addressing locations way beyond (after) it?

Comment: @Inian Yes, exactly. But I was expecting something to get broken, or the application throwing some kind of exception. Instead, I just got that unexpected( for me) behavior.

Comment: @Deanie this is C++, so the cast is necessary (granted C was tagged)

Comment: In `c` and `c++` this is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: As mentioned in the answer below, you don't get errors for _accessing_ out of bound memory locations. It is just that you don't have control over what's happening further.

Comment: @Inian So, would that change if instead I had used "malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000)" ? and only iterated to that limit?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons it was originally tagged as c.  Most people who don't know how to program in c++ often mark both languages.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: That's a start! Yes. The idea is play within the memory you own and control

Comment: @Inian Thanks! :)

Comment: "I was expecting something to get broken" The language never *promises* to break anything in particular. "or the application throwing some kind of exception"  So it didn't do that. Maybe *that* is what's broken?

Comment: *"Why malloc() accepted the value of "1" but then I keep writing until 100 thousands addresses with no problem?"* think for a second that memory is like a piece of paper. You can draw a square on it and say that you can only draw a picture inside that square. But what is preventing you from drawing outside of the square other than the discipline to obey the rules? Same thing here, `malloc` allocates memory for your, but it's your job as a programmer to obey the rules and never to access memory outside the boundaries.

Comment: Compile with `-fsanitize=address` to get more interesting feedback at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int j=0 ; j < 999 ; j++) {
        limit++;
        *x=666;
        x++; <---- yikes
    }
```

Here you are incrementing it to point to some memory that you didn't allocate. Invoking undefined behavior when you in next itertion dereference it and write something to it.

Anything after `*x=666` is in the realm of undefined behavior.

To answer your questions, I would say `malloc` does what it is supposed to do. It allocates memory - the amount you request. `C` doesn't provide any warning or exception on accessing out of bound memory.

You asked why do use `malloc`? You don't have to. You can simply do this using `c++`

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(int j=0 ; j < 999 ; j++) {
        limit++;
        v.push_back(666);
        /* other work */
    }
```

Third questions answer you already know - you have incremented the pointer value and that is being increased and printed.  When you tried to access it  - well that's where thing went wrong for this code.

Back to `C`:

Yes you can do that - you can allocate as much as you need. And as you allocated now it's your turn to access it carefully. Your use of `malloc` for a `C` compiler is a bit off. If I have to write a C code out of it - I wil write like this

```
int* x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
if( x == NULL ){
  perror("Malloc failed");
  exit(1);
}
for(size i=0; i<1000; i++){
   x[i] = 666;
}
```

When you allocated for `1000` ints - yes it will work fine. And instead of incrementing `x` you can simply do it like this. No harm following the simple approach.

---

If you wanted to initialized the `1000` elements with `666`, you can do this in `C++`

```
std::vector<int> v(1000,666);
```

Comment: Would that change if I had used "malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000)"?

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. It cleared up a lot what was going on with my code. Awesome man.